# Detaching CK Editor from an element with no name and Id value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm working on a CMS where elements are created dynamically and some are preloaded, I need to detach the CK Editor from those preloaded elements and attach the CK Editor again to all editable elements in the target area including the preloaded ones.

```
I'm in this loop, that gives me the target div being appended and I need to remove the CK Editor from the preloaded elements with CK Editor without knowing their Ids and name values.




   //here 'thisElement' is the array of all editable elements being appended including preloaded ones
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < thisElement.length; i++) {

                      //something like this, this doesn't work
                      //  CKEDITOR.destroy(thisElement.get(a));

                      //or something like this, this doesn't work
                       // CKEDITOR.editable(thisElement.get(i));

                        CKEDITOR.inline(thisElement.get(i));

                        for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                            delete CKEDITOR.instances[name];
                        }
                    };
```

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a similar thing. I add and remove rows from a table who's entries are bound to a collection. Because of this I have to reseed the indexes in the DOM and also remove and reattach all my CKEditors.

Below is what works for me, but it does remove ALL editors from the current page.

**EDIT**: Added check to see if CKEditor name is in an array of DOM element names.

```
  var domElements = ["element1", "element2"];

        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            if (CKEDITOR.instances.hasOwnProperty(instance)) {
                if (jQuery.inArray(CKEDITOR.instances[instance].name, domElements) !== -1) {
                    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].destroy();
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I however just need to detach CK Editor from the editable elements within the 'thisElement' aka the elements being dropped. any idea for that?

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil - Can you show whats in thisElement. i.e. is it names?

Comment: Yes, It is an array of some editable paragraphs and headings [complete Dom elements]. and I'm applying CK Editor on them when they drop using CKEDITOR.inline().

Comment: They are DOM elements

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil - I've edited my answer. The only thing I can think of is to validate the name of the editor before acting upon it. My local dev seems to be having problems with the inArray function.. so it does actually error on that line!.. but there are alternatives like indexOf. Hopefully yours is ok.

Comment: this is something I need but it says this in the console: editor-incorrect-destroy and after destroying it removes all ck editors + the official site states this issue as : The editor is being destroyed before it is fully initialized.

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil - Perhaps its the location of your destroy script and you are having a conflict. Put some alerts in and ensure that your destroy is not being called at the wrong time. My editor initialization is inside document ready. The destroys are at a click of a button.

Comment: Yup, you were right, the position of my destroy event was not right, I fixed that but still, I couldn't find my right solution.

can you look at this question, please? 

https://stackoverflow.com/q/51060669/5360889