# CK Editor font-size, font-style, font-type dropdown take a while to appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm working on a CMS where we have a lot of elements with pre-loaded CK Editors everything works fine including the drop downs for text-color etc but the drop downs for font-size, font-style, font-type takes a while before appearing, See attached:

[image]

PS: I am using CkEditor.inline to fire Ck Editor on it

Can someone please help with why is it happening?

Comment: Sorry... not come across this issue before.

Comment: @Wheels73 no worries and thanks for all the help.